# Can an extension similar to Simple Notes (Opera) be developed in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have a very limited knowledge on the manipulation of overlays and XUL elements in Firefox extensions but I am interested to know if it's possible to do something like [this "Simple Notes" Opera add-on](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/simple-notes/) in Firefox browser interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be, and probably has been, done, or at least something close.

You can search AMO for [Notes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=notes) or [Note](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=note) and look through the results for an extension that does what you want.